# Email processing with filtering

Tags: mysql, email, outlook, text-files

can anyone guide me int he right direction?

What i'm trying to achieve is this:

-Receive an email, something with the content:

SUBJECT: JOKE OF THE DAY
BODY:    This is the joke content  today is 10/10/2010

-Check my email automatically and IF the subject is "JOKE OF THE DAY" i want to automatically process this email to filter the contents with my own rules and to put them into a database, or create a txt, cvs file, etc.

Example: 
FILTER "This is the joke content" and send it to one field of the database or line on a file
FILTER "today is 10/10/2010" and put the data into a field of the database or on a new line on a file

Any idea on how to do this?

Is there any application out there that does this out of the box? Without requiring me to develop one from scratch, i don't want to reinvent the wheel.
Is there a plugin or something to do this on thunderbird, outlook, evolution?

What would be the best approach to this? Any ideas would be great. I believe that there might be something out there that does this, but I can't find anything that does this for me.

Comment: forgot to add the other obvious option. Is there an option also when receiving emails via unix system? Maybe a php, phyton script to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a solution for a unix-like system (from your comment), have a look at [procmail](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~ian/procmail.html); this software is available on many systems and will do what you want (filter email messages by headers/content, and then channel to a script or folder of your choice).

Comment: Thank you very much I also found something similar of what I was looking for. And a unix-like system is probably the best way to handle this. I'm also looking for a way to do this via imaplib using python.